# Applying CSS "display: none" causes higher elements to drop

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a custom navigation bar class and this bug involves the mechanism which handles drop-down menus and such. Below is an example and explanation of the relevant test code.

HTML:

```
<div class="nav-bar" id="main">
    <div class="menu-container" id="menu1">
        <div class="menu-label"> Menu Head 1 </div>
        <div class="menu-list-container">
            <div class="menu-item"> Item 1 </div>
            <div class="menu-item"> Item 2 </div>
            <div class="menu-item"> Item 3 </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-container" id="menu2">
        <div class="menu-label"> Menu Head 2 </div>
        <div class="menu-list-container">
            <div class="menu-item"> Item 1 </div>
            <div class="menu-item"> Item 2 </div>
            <div class="menu-item"> Item 3 </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.nav-menu-container {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

This is the only CSS that needed to not be default. I.e. every div except the `nav-menu-container` elements is set to `display: block;`.
From here, the one other CSS change comes from JS setting the height of the `nav-bar` element to whatever the height of a `menu-label` element (in screenshots I highlight the `nav-bar` element to show this). 
Next, I have screenshots of the test page showing first the unaltered page, and then the page with one of the `menu-list-container` elements set to `display: none;` and shows the bug I am referring to.
[image]
[image]

So my question is why does the `menu-label` element drop down rather than just staying at the top? I did notice that it's just aligning its bottom edge with the bottom edge of the other `menu-container`, because if I set the other `menu-list` to `display: none;` each of the labels return to the top of the screen. Does anyone know what causes this? Or a clean way to make this not happen?

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `inline-block` elements are aligned along their *baseline*, which is the last line of visible text (if there is text in there, which is the case here).

So you just have to add `vertical-align: top;` to the CSS rule for `.nav-menu-container` and they will align as desired.

Comment: This worked perfectly, knew it would be something simple like this. Thanks for the enlightenment!